# Laravel Email Logging Channel

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-5.6, swiftmailer

I have a Laravel 5.6 project and I want to configure it such that high level errors are emailed to me.
I have added an email channel to logging.php config file and specified Monolog's Swiftmailer as the handler but since it needs a mailer instance and message in its constructor I don't know what values should be supplied.
Any help is much appreciated.

PS: I do know there are packages for this purpose but think this should be simple enough to do manually.

```
'email' => [
    'driver' => 'monolog',
    'handler' => Monolog\Handler\SwiftMailerHandler::class,
    'handler_with' => [
        'mailer' => ?,
        'message' => ?,
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 1):

With Lavarel 7.x you can solve it like this

```
'smtp-sys' => [
'driver' => 'monolog',
'level' => 'info',
'handler' => SwiftMailerHandler::class,
    'handler_with' => [
        'mailer' => new Swift_Mailer( (new Swift_SmtpTransport(env('MAIL_HOST_SYS'), env('MAIL_PORT_SYS'), env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls')))->setUsername(env('MAIL_USERNAME_SYS'))->setPassword(env('MAIL_PASSWORD_SYS'))),
        'message' => (new Swift_Message('[LOG] Exception'))
            ->setFrom([env('MAIL_USERNAME_SYS') => 'Dev'])
            ->setTo([env('MAIL_USERNAME_SYS') => 'Dev'])
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little late but from [Symfony SwiftMailer documentation](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/sending.html) you should use something like this:

```
...
'email' => [
    'driver' => 'monolog',
    'level' => 'critical',
    'handler' => SwiftMailerHandler::class,
    'handler_with' => [
        'mailer' => (new Swift_SmtpTransport(env('MAIL_HOST'), env('MAIL_PORT'), env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION')))
            ->setUsername(env('MAIL_USERNAME'))
            ->setPassword(env('MAIL_PASSWORD')),
        'message' => (new Swift_Message('[LOG] Exception'))
            ->setFrom([env('LOG_MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS') => env('LOG_MAIL_FROM_NAME')])
            ->setTo([env('LOG_MAIL_TO_ADDRESS') => 'Dev'])
            ->setBody('Here is the message itself')

    ],
    'formatter' => HtmlFormatter::class,
],
...
```